# Можно ли обойтись без двойного НЕ (!!) в данном примере ?Я думаю оно тут лишнее

Tags: javascript, функции

По заданию:Напишите функцию `checkSpam(str)`, которая возвращает true, если строка str содержит „viagra“ или „XXX“, а иначе false.Функция должна быть нечувствительна к регистру.

Вот такой вопрос: а если не ставить 2 восклицательных знака(двойное НЕ)... обе проверки выдают 0, получаем false - то, что и надо по условию, одна или обе проверки дают значение больше или меньше нуля - это true - опять же удовлетворяет условию ...

Вопрос зачем нужно это двойное отрицание(true-false-true;false-true-false)?

Оно тут не лишнее ??

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Just a Generic Page</title>
  <script>
    function checkSpam(str) {
      var lowstr = str.toLowerCase();

      return !!(~lowstr.indexOf("viagra") || ~lowstr.indexOf("XXX"));
    }
    checkSpam('buy ViAgRA now');
    checkSpam('free xxxxx');
    checkSpam("innocent rabbit");
  </script>
</head>

<body>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: в данном случае результаты функции `checkSpam` вообще не используются, значит можно удалить функцию полностью

Comment: Классный троллинг)) ну а всё таки.. нужно ли тут двойное НЕ?)

Comment: все зависит от того как будет использоваться данная функция. `!!` гарантирует, что выходное значение будет либо `true`, либо `false`. То есть все будет работать в случае проверок на равенство `checkSpam('buy ViAgRA now') == true`. Если убрать, то выражение `checkSpam('buy ViAgRA now') == true` вернет false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логический оператор ! всегда возвращает тип boolean, поэтому двойное применение этого оператора можно использовать для конвертирования объектов в этот тип.

```js
console.log(!true);
console.log(true);
console.log(!0);
console.log(!!0);
```

Операция || примененная к числам возвращает либо левое число если оно не 0, либо правое. Двойное отрицание в данном случае необходимо чтобы гарантировать контракт - функция должна всегда возвращать тип boolean. Наличие этой операции не влияет на результат только если его позднее привести к типу boolean.

```js
function checkSpam(str) {
  var lowstr = str.toLowerCase();

  return (~lowstr.indexOf("viagra") || ~lowstr.indexOf("XXX"));
}
console.log(checkSpam('buy ViAgRA now'));
console.log(checkSpam('free xxxxx'));
console.log(checkSpam("innocent rabbit"));
```

Чтобы избавиться от необходимости использовать двойное отрицание, необходимо изменить код таким образом, чтобы он всегда оперировал со значениями типа boolean.

```js
function checkSpam(str) {
  var lowstr = str.toLowerCase();

  return (lowstr.indexOf("viagra") != -1 || lowstr.indexOf("XXX") != -1);
}
console.log(checkSpam('buy ViAgRA now'));
console.log(checkSpam('free xxxxx'));
console.log(checkSpam("innocent rabbit"));
```

Comment: `есть два оператора ! и !!.` = ты не прав. Оператор один `!`

Comment: @Grundy, логично. переписал это место

Comment: в последним примере `~` не нужен можно сразу сравнивать с -1

Comment: @Grundy, согласен. так будет правильнее. Функцию видимо написал человек, которые не любит простых решений :-)